# Images moving when one image is resized (CSS and HTML)

Tags: css

So I have some images that I'm smoothly scaling up on mouse over.  It looks great, but I noticed that other images near it are kind of moving to accomodate more or less space when one resizes.  I want them to just stay in place.  Here is the code:

```
img
{
width:130;
height:130;
margin:15px;
background-color:transparent;
background-size:100%;

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
} 

img:hover
{
width:150;
height:150;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

each of this images should be placed in any inline-block container, which has a static width and enougn height for images to scroll up and down. CSS for this container:

```
.image_container {
    width: 130px;
    height: 145px;/* reserved space for image to scroll up */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This didn't really help.  I know that `display:block` skips lines, so I tried `display:inline`.  All the elements still moved over to accomodate the resized element

Comment: i'm sorry, i meant `display: inline-block;`

Comment: It still isn't working.  The image is just changing its margin, and all the other images are moving up to accomodate it again

Answer (score 0):

It's usually kind of hard to expand a child element beyond the bounds of it's parent element without disturbing any siblings of the parent.

I whipped this up just because I wanted to. It uses box-shadow to make it feel like the image it's overlapping the other images, with quite simple CSS3.

It's released under the [WTFPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL).

http://jsfiddle.net/dWBwW/23/